# modify URL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect any sub site to main URL.

From

`http://example.com/one/two`

To

`http://example.com/`

This is my current .htaccess

```js
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm parking-page.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^example\.org.? example\.org? [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1?

FallbackResource index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule (.*) /webone/two
```

Comment: I would like to redirect example.com/webone/two to example.com, without /webone/two

Comment: I think I need a regex of some sort, that will take any kind of subs and redirect them to index